# Postgres - Update all values in a JSON object to be text

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a JSON column that is full of different keys and some of the values in it are numbers but I want all the values to be text. For example, I have `{"budget": 500, "budget_id": 100, ...[dozens more keys]}`, but I want it to be `{"budget":"500", "budget_id": "100"}`. I am hoping there is a single query that will blindly spit back a JSON object whose values are all text. Something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET data = data || --python-sql psuedo-code -> [key:quote_literal(value) for key in data.keys()];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is. First flatten the JSON into a set of key-value pairs using `json_each_text` (value as text) and aggregate back into JSON using `json_object_agg`.

```sql
update my_table
set data = (select json_object_agg(key, value) from json_each_text(data));
```

This approach can be used for other transformations too.
It might be a better idea to make a view instead of modifying the original data:

```sql
create view my_table_v as 
 select <the other fields>, 
        (select json_object_agg(key, value) from json_each_text(data)) as data 
 from my_table;
```

Comment: +1! I was just fiddling with this problem, here's a demo with edge cases (null, already text, sneaky quotes) : [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c563be0ebf1441632213d58ff61eca0d) (Postgres >=10)

Comment: thank you--this is definitely a helpful start & seems to work well on a table of a single row. I haven't yet been able to adjust it to work on a table that has multiple rows.

Comment: Well, a single row or multiple rows should not make a difference except in execution time if you have millions of rows.

Comment: i think for my use case i needed to add a group by ID statement that would keep each row of the data column separate?

Comment: If you need to do the transformation into a new table then I would suggest using `select into`.

Comment: i needed to update the original column from my multi-row table with the new column rather than create a whole new table. it looks like `select into` only works for insert queries?

Comment: Basically it is `create` plus `insert`(s). But you can update your table in-place, w/o a second copy.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm: the standard compliant `create table ... as select ...` is recommended over the non-standard `select into`

Answer (score 0):

i think based off of the helpful earlier answer given in [Postgres - Update all values in a JSON object to be text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73445902/postgres-update-all-values-in-a-json-object-to-be-text/73446098#73446098) I was able to adjust the query:

```
update my_table orig
set data = text_table.text_data from (
    select same_as_orig.id, json_object_agg(k, v) text_data          
    from my_table same_as_orig, json_each_text(data::json) _(k, v)
    group by same_as_orig.id
    ) text_table
where orig.id = text_table.id;
```

Comment: Maybe you might think about not updating the original column but creating a view with modified JSON column. Replacing native data with their representation as formatted text (which is basically a presentation) is not a good idea. I have updated the answer.